# How to remove Duplicate Accounts?

Tags: apex, data-loader

In my `salesforce org`, I have a list of **Accounts** which was loaded externally using `CSV file` using `Data loader tool`. The problem is that 3 team member of my team uploaded same data thrice and thats why duplicates Account data coming. I need to remove all those multi-duplicate account.

How can I remove that? What is the correct way of doing this rectification?
I assume my org might have 1000 unique Accounts, so due to developers error, count has become 3000. This is terrible.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only talking about 3000 records and you're only worried about exact name dups (ignoring case), a primitive script would also work:

```
List<Account> allAccounts = [SELECT Name FROM Account];
Set<String> accountNames = new Set<String>();
List<Account> accountsToDelete = new List<Account>();
for (Account a : allAccounts) {
    if (accountNames.contains(a.Name)) {
        accountsToDelete.add(a);
    }
    else {
        accountNames.add(a.Name);
    }
}
delete accountsToDelete;
```

Comment: Thanks. How we can considering using ignore case ?

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like all the names are identical matches, so the answer I provided would be appropriate. However - to answer your follow up question, you could use `containsIgnoreCase()` instead of `contains()`

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't done anything with them, it might just be easier to delete all 3,000 records and re-import. As an alternative, you can use Duplicate Rules to automatically identify all the duplicates, now and in the future, and even write some Execute Anonymous code to remove all the duplicates:

```
DuplicateRecordSet[] drs = [SELECT (SELECT RecordId FROM DuplicateRecordItems) FROM DuplicateRecordSet WHERE SObjectType='Account'];
Account[] accounts = new Account[0];
for(DuplicateRecordSet dupe: drs) {
  // We use 1 here to ignore the first entry
  for(Integer i = 1; i < dupe.DuplicateRecordItems.size(); i++) {
    accounts.add(new Account(Id=dupe.DuplicateRecordItems[i].RecordId));
  }
}
delete accounts;
```

For what its worth, Duplicate Rules can also be configured to catch fuzzy matches (e.g. "The Gap" versus "Gap, The", as well as case variations).

Comment: `SELECT (SELECT RecordId FROM DuplicateRecordItems) FROM DuplicateRecordSet WHERE SObjectType='Account' ` - This query does not pull any records.

Comment: @user4567570 You won't get any results until you configure duplicate rules in the setup screen and allow initial processing to finish. The code I demonstrated here works in my developer org.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the success file install Dupcatcher and merge the accounts

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pull out the success log file which is getting stored into this system and delete those ids from data loader delete option.